# Mongodb aggregation retrieve count and result

Tags: mongodb, sorting, filter, aggregation-framework, match

I would like to count the result of filtered records and return the records after its limited:

```
{
  "count": 6,
  "data": [{ ... }, { ... }, { ... }]
}
```

With the command below:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { timestamp: { $gte: "1999-07-16T19:20:30.45Z" } } },
  { $sort: { timestamp: -1, _id: -1 } },
  { 
    $count: "count",
  },
  { $limit: 3 },
])
```

it returns

```
{ "count" : 6 }
```

My question:

1. how do I insert the records to data?
2. Will the data have max size of 16 MB?

I would like to not use facet to contain the $match and $sort pipeline because I read that it doesnt utilize index...

Comment: using $group, group all documents by _id as "null" and $push all the required details into "data" array. Post your attempt in the question, will help you if stuck. Read this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#count-the-number-of-documents-in-a-collection and https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#count-the-number-of-documents-in-a-collection

Comment: @DheemanthBhat are all the fields really need to be specified? because i want to include all fields and there are a lot

Comment: u can have all fields in an object with single key and then try. Post your schema. Let me check if anything can be done.